# ListView is not rendering inside ScrollView and StackLayout with orientation horizontal in ios - nativescript-vue

Tags: android, ios, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

ListView is not rendering when implemented inside ScrollView and StackLayout with orientation horizontal in ios but same is rendering in android - vertical and horizontal scaling table

```
  <ScrollView orientation="horizontal">
    <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
      <RadListView for="todo in monthlyMeterData">
        <v-template>
          <GridLayout columns="150,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100">
            <Label :text="todo.region" col="0"/>
            <Label :text="getMonthData(todo.monthlyCount,'January')" col="1"/>
            <Label :text="getMonthData(todo.monthlyCount,'January')" col="2"/>
            <Label :text="getMonthData(todo.monthlyCount,'January')" col="3"/>
            <Label :text="getMonthData(todo.monthlyCount,'January')" col="4"/>
            <Label :text="getMonthData(todo.monthlyCount,'January')" col="5"/>
            <Label :text="getMonthData(todo.monthlyCount,'January')" col="6"/>
            <Label :text="getMonthData(todo.monthlyCount,'January')" col="7"/>
            <Label :text="getMonthData(todo.monthlyCount,'January')" col="8"/>
            <Label :text="getMonthData(todo.monthlyCount,'January')" col="9"/>
            <Label :text="getMonthData(todo.monthlyCount,'January')" col="10"/>
            <Label :text="getMonthData(todo.monthlyCount,'January')" col="11"/>
            <Label :text="getMonthData(todo.monthlyCount,'January')" col="12"/>
            <Label :text="getMonthData(todo.monthlyCount,'January')" col="13"/>
          </GridLayout>
        </v-template>
      </RadListView>
    </StackLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

[Ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeXqO.png) [Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU2Nq.png)

Comment: The below suggestion is correct but it is not a good practice to nest multiple scrollable elements so you might want to rethink the UI. Also, the ListView / RadListView is not showing on iOS as this is the native behavior for the native elements that are standing behind them (UITableVidew). The thing is that the ListView & R\adListView will need either an explicit height or to be nested within a parent with explicit height. In two words - avoid nesting scrollable elements and use height for creating the listview on iOS (e..g. you can use <GridLayout rows="*"><RadListView row="0">)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, on iOS, the RadListView width is not being properly calculated. Since you have columns with fixed width, you can force the total width (1450). Also, you don't need that `<StackLayout>`. I got it working with this code:

```
<ScrollView orientation="horizontal">
  <RadListView for="todo in monthlyMeterData" width="1450">
    <v-template>
      <GridLayout columns="150,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100">
      <!-- ... -->
```

I hope it helps!